# Unable to check manifest.json

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have been struggling to deploy a Shiny app. I keep getting the error "Error parsing manifest: Manifest file count (6742) greater than maximum allowed (6000)".

I made sure I delete all hidden files, yet I get this error. Is there a way to check the manifest file. I see that it fails to deploy. There are no logs and no clues on why it is complaining.

Any help will be appreciated.

Ganesh